# К чему относятся урны: к зданию или к перрону?

Tags: грамотная-речь, запятые, тире

В легкодоступных элементах здания, перрона — в урнах для мусора.

Answer (score 1):

*В легкодоступных элементах здания, перрона — в урнах для мусора.*

Бот Ботович верно отметил, что контекст недостаточен для понимания смысла, однако тире говорит о том, что "в урнах для мусора" - это приложение, относящееся к однородным членам "здания, перрона". Я думаю, что смысл как раз в том, что урны для мусора - легкодоступные элементы здания и перрона.

Answer (score 0):

Вы "съели" слишком большой кусок текста, из-за чего достаточно трудно понять содержание. На мой взгляд, текст был таким:

**В здании мусор выбрасывают в его легкодоступные элементы, на перроне — в урны.**

Таким образом, урны относятся к перрону.

**UPD**: Артём, я сам не понимаю, почему система их отметила.

Comment: спасибо )))))))

Comment: Я уже понял.)) Пробелы лишние потому что убрали.

Comment: Зря Вы только в ответе прокомментировали. К нему это не относится. Комментарии на то и есть, чтобы такие вещи обсуждать.